# SQL Update from Comma Delimited Data

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to perform an update in SQL in a specific table to update records based on comma delimited data.

Table trying to update is `EnterpriseUser`
Trying to set certain users to `ViewGroupdID = 53`
If the `IVRID` is '4457520','4457856','4458070','4458117','4458535'

I can only figure out how to update a single record using `Where IVRID = '4457176'` but not for multiple IVRID's

My current code is...

```
UPDATE [XT].[dbo].[EnterpriseUser]
SET [XT].[dbo].[EnterpriseUser].ViewGroupID = 53
Where IVRID = '4457176'
```

Thoughts or suggestions? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be solved easily using `IN` instead of `=`:

```
UPDATE [XT].[dbo].[EnterpriseUser]
SET [XT].[dbo].[EnterpriseUser].ViewGroupID = 53
Where IVRID IN ('4457520','4457856','4458070','4458117','4458535')
```

The `IN` condition allows you to specify a list of values, each of which will be (in this case) updated.

Here's some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm) about using the `IN` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "IN" operator in the WHERE clause and pass them like so:

```
UPDATE [XT].[dbo].[EnterpriseUser]
SET [XT].[dbo].[EnterpriseUser].ViewGroupID = 53
Where IVRID IN ('4457520','4457856','4458070','4458117','4458535')
```